# ANTLR4: How can I recognize words from an alphabet?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I am new to Antl4. I have an antlr grammar file that consists of something similar to:

```
consonant : 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'f' ; 
vowel : 'a' | 'e' | 'i' ; 
connector : ':' | '-' ; 

cseq : (consonant)+ ; 
vseq : (vowel)+ ;

prefix : cseq vseq ;

word : (cseq vseq | cseq)+ ;
```

From my understanding, even though these lines are at the bottom of a file, they're still considered rules. My parse tree captures each individual letter instead of treating them as lexical items - or words. How can I change these rules into lexer statements?

Comment: Yes, `word` is a rule. You don't use it, but it's ok, it won't match. The string literals 'a', 'b', etc., are "lexer rules" so to speak. They are declared for you by Antlr implicitly. That is why each letter is an individual token. It's generally a good idea to explicitly declare lexer rules for each string literal you use in the grammar, e.g., `A: 'a'; B: 'b';...`. You can still use the literal in the parser rule. The order of the parser rules is not significant. Order of lexer rules is significant, but only when matching the same string of characters of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to keep in mind.

- parser rules are rules beginning with lower case letters
- lexer rules are those whose name begins with an uppercase character (fairly common convention is to make then all uppercase)
- if you put a literal character in a parser rule (all of your rules are parser rules, as they begin with lower case characters), ANTLR will synthesize a TOKEN rule for those characters.

Since it appears that you want a word to be a lexical item (i.e. Token), you could do something along the lines of:

```
fragment CONSONANT : 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'f' ; 
fragment VOWEL : 'a' | 'e' | 'i' ; 
CONNECTOR : ':' | '-' ; // not sure what you intend for this

fragment CSEQ: CONSONANT+ ; 
fragment VSEQ : VOWEL+ ;

PREFIX : CSEQ VSEQ ; // not sure what you intend for this

WORD : (CSEQ VSEQ | CSEQ)+ ;
```

(That's making quite a few assumptions about your intention.)

Main point, if you want `WORD`s to be single tokens, they need to be defined as a Lexer rule.

If you want to compose rules for Lexer rules, you can define `fragment` rules.  These rules can be used to compose Lexer rules, but will not, themselves, be recognized as tokens.

With the changes here, you should be able to use `WORD` in a parser rule, and have all the characters that make up your `WORD` in a single Token.